# Infinite loop reading files via FTP with Perl

Tags: perl, file, parsing, ftp

I have the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::FTP;

my $counter;

my $ftp = Net::FTP->new( "ftp.metagenomics.anl.gov", Debug => 0 )
    or die "Cannot connect.\n";
$ftp->login() or die "Login problems.\n";
$ftp->cwd("/projects") or die "Cannot change directory.\n";

for my $directory ( $ftp->ls ) {
    $ftp->cwd($directory);
    my ( $remote_file_content, $remote_file_handle );
    open( $remote_file_handle, ">", \$remote_file_content );
    $ftp->get( "metadata.project-" . $directory . ".json", $remote_file_handle )
        or die "Get failed.\n";
    while ( my $line = $remote_file_content ) {
        $counter++;
        if ( $line =~ /"biome":{"unit":"","required":"1","value":"([A-Za-z0-9_\-. ]*)",/ ) {
            print $counter. "\t" . $directory . "\t" . $1 . "\n";
        }
    }
    close $remote_file_content;
    $ftp->cwd("..");
}
```

However, the first file is being read over and over again... It is like an infinite loop and i do not know why it never finishes to read the same file. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried commenting out certain lines of code to see where the issue is? If you have found out which line is causing the problem, have you done any reading to see **why** it might be causing an infinite loop?

Comment: Track your various file names, print out the list from `ls`, which directory is opened, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
    while (my $line = $remote_file_content) {
        $counter++;
        if ($line =~ /"biome":{"unit":"","required":"1","value":"([A-Za-z0-9_\-. ]*)",/) {
            print $counter."\t".$directory."\t".$1."\n";
        }
    }
```

This loop will only end once `$remote_file_content` is false (i.e. empty), because you have no `last` or other way to exit the loop.
But, you never change `$remote_file_content` in this loop.
This means, once you enter it you will never leave the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to process each line in the file separately or as a whole?

If you're doing it as a whole, get rid of the while loop and do this:

```
for my $directory ( $ftp->ls ) {
    $ftp->cwd($directory);
    my ( $remote_file_content, $remote_file_handle );
    open( $remote_file_handle, ">", \$remote_file_content );
    $ftp->get( "metadata.project-" . $directory . ".json", $remote_file_handle )
        or die "Get failed.\n";
    $counter++;
    if ( $remote_file_content =~ /"biome":{"unit":"","required":"1","value":"([A-Za-z0-9_\-. ]*)",/ ) {
        print $counter. "\t" . $directory . "\t" . $1 . "\n";
    }
    close $remote_file_handle;
    $ftp->cwd("..");
}
```

If you want to process each line separately:

```
for my $directory ( $ftp->ls ) {
    $ftp->cwd($directory);
    my ( $remote_file_content, $remote_file_handle );
    open( $remote_file_handle, ">", \$remote_file_content );
    $ftp->get( "metadata.project-" . $directory . ".json", $remote_file_handle )
        or die "Get failed.\n";
    foreach my $line (split "\n", $remote_file_content ) {
        $counter++;
        if ( $line =~ /"biome":{"unit":"","required":"1","value":"([A-Za-z0-9_\-. ]*)",/ ) {
            print $counter. "\t" . $directory . "\t" . $1 . "\n";
        }
    }
    close $remote_file_handle;
    $ftp->cwd("..");
}
```

You're closing the file name instead of the file handle, the close is failing, you just don't know it because the close gets called automatically when the variable goes out of scope.